# Does the Silverlight runtime automatically install via Windows Update?

Tags: .net, silverlight, installation

Does the Silverlight runtime have to be downloaded/installed deliberately, or these days is there a chance that a fully-patched Windows machine will already have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on wikipedia on windows 7 it's available in the additional updates from windows updates.